# Windows Application Log Events being 'missed' somehow with my EventLog

Tags: c#, event-log

I've written an application, a component of which watches for Events being raised in the Windows Application Log with a certain Source and EventID in order to parse data from them. However, it appears to miss some of these events for no readily apparent reason.

I have included debug messages to try to see where the issue is - this takes the form of comments sent to a text field.

**When an Entry is written to the application log, a time-stamped message is added to the debug text field, and `parseApplicationLogEntry()` is called.**

```
private void eventLogApplication_EntryWritten(object sender,
                                          System.Diagnostics.EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    txtDebug.Text = txtDebug.Text + "\n " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + 
        + ": Application Log has been written."; 
    parseApplicationLogEntry(); 
}
```

**The application log entry is parsed, and the Source and EventID are looked at to determine if they are what we are looking for. A time-stamped message is added to the debug text showing the Source and EventID found.**

```
private void parseApplicationLogEntry()
{
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application"); 
    int entry = log.Entries.Count - 1; 
    string logMessage = log.Entries[entry].Message;
    string logSource = log.Entries[entry].Source; 
    string logEventID = log.Entries[entry].InstanceId.ToString(); 
    log.Close(); 
    txtDebug.Text = txtDebug.Text + "\n " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + 
        ": Application Log Source is " + logSource;
    txtDebug.Text = txtDebug.Text + "\n " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + 
        ": Application Log EventID is " + logEventID; 

    if (logSource == "ExpectedSource" & logEventID == "ExpectedEventID")
    {
        // Do stuff 
    } 
}
```

The behaviour is as expected much of the time, however sometimes there is very odd behaviour.

For example, 13 logs were written to the application log. 3 with the looked-for source, and 10 with another source. The debug text shows 13 entries were seen, all with the unfamiliar source...

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to access the EventLog in this way to review the newest entries.

Instead of calling a method to iterate through the EventLog each time a new Entry is written, it is simpler (and safer) to access the Entry more directly using the event handler which triggers each time an Entry is written.

```
private void eventLog_Application_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    // Process e.Entry    
}
```